# Как обрезать не нужную часть из начала и конца ссылки?

Tags: mysql, mysqli

У меня в базе хранится много ссылок в таком виде https://mywebpage.com/category-name/post-name/#about-us

Мне нужно получить только

> /category-name/post-name/

Раньше я использоавл такой запрос

```
SELECT DISTINCT TRIM(TRIM(BOTH 'https://mywebpage.com' FROM TRIM(TRAILING SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, '/', -1)  FROM url))) AS url FROM stats
```

Но теперь в базе стали появляться другие ссылки с другими доменами и думаю надо выбиарать все справа начиная с .com :/

Comment: Два раза SUBSTRING_INDEX() по слэшу.

Comment: туплю с синтаксисом, не работает :( TRIM(TRIM(LEADING SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, '/', 3) FROM TRIM(TRAILING SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, '/', -1)  FROM url)) AS url FROM stats

Comment: `SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, '/', 4), '/', -2)`. Ну если прёт - добавить потом в начало и конец по слэшу вульгарным CONCAT().

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему так

```
SELECT DISTINCT TRIM( TRIM(LEADING SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, '/', 3) FROM TRIM(TRAILING SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, '/', -1)  FROM url
```